# How do I stop a "while loop" from getting and saving user inputs while it is looping?

Tags: python

```
import time
t = 500
while t: # while t > 0 for clarity 
    try:
        # Timer
        mins = t // 60
        secs = t % 60
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        response = input("-- Press 'enter' to unpause \
                        \n-- Type s to skip timer \
                        \n-- Type e to close program \
                        \nYour Response Here: ")
```

How to Replicate: While timer is running, specifically `try block`, press keyboard letter keys randomly. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to stop the loop and you'll see the keys you pressed earlier.

**Q:** How do I stop a `while loop` from getting user inputs and transferring it to the next code block, specifically an `input()`

Comment: What is ```t,s```?

Comment: *"How do I stop these"* - what is "these"?

Comment: Also, not that you necessarily need it, but if you want question tips check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Sujay Thanks for pointing that, I noticed the code was vague.

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to stop

Comment: @Sujay  Of course, I've edited the question. If still vague, I've put on a very short & quick instruction on how to replicate the problem.

Comment: [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution for windows : [msvcrt](https://docs.python.org/3/library/msvcrt.html)

```
msvcrt.kbhit()
```

> Return True if a keypress is waiting to be read.

```
msvcrt.getch()
```

> Read a keypress and return the resulting character as a byte string.
> Nothing is echoed to the console.

**This will clear:**

```
import time
import msvcrt

t = 500
while t: # while t > 0 for clarity 
    try:
        # Timer
        mins = t // 60
        secs = t % 60
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        # clear 
        while msvcrt.kbhit():
            msvcrt.getch()

        response = input("-- Press 'enter' to unpause \
                        \n-- Type s to skip timer \
                        \n-- Type e to close program \
                        \nYour Response Here: ")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Awesome... how did you know about the module "msvcrt"? Have you worked with these module before or is there some kind of trick to find out other modules?

Comment: Note that msvcrt is a Windows-only module.

Comment: Trick is googling right keyword :D , @TERMINATOR I have updated explanation and shared doc link.

Comment: @Abhi Interesting, what did you google to get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

On linux:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import termios
import fcntl
import os
import time


def getchar():
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    oldatribut = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    newatribut = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    newatribut[3] = newatribut[3] & ~termios.ICANON & ~termios.ECHO
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSANOW, newatribut)
    oldflags = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    mychar = None
    try:
        mychar = sys.stdin.read(1)
    except IOError:
        pass
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSAFLUSH, oldatribut)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, oldflags)
    return mychar


keys: str = ""
t = 500
while t:  # while t > 0 for clarity
    try:
        # Timer
        mins = t // 60
        secs = t % 60
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        key = getchar()
        if key:
            keys += key
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # print(f"You have '{keys}' key pressed")
        response = input(f"-- Press 'enter' to unpause \
                        \n-- Type s to skip timer \
                        \n-- Type e to close program \
                        \nYour Response Here: {keys}")
        break
```

This work in terminal, not in Pycharm etc.